# Spacing in TikZ node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a TikZ figure where a node contains text in both normal and script size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw, align=center, text width=2cm, minimum width=2.32cm, minimum height=2cm]
    {\textbf{Big}\\\textbf{stuff}\\{\scriptsize Some, small, stuff}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The distance between the third and fourth line looks too large.

[image: node image]

Am I switching correctly to script size?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to say "too small" rather than "too large"?

Comment: Wrongly spelled and the opposite what I meant. Yes, too large. I am sorry. Original description updated.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [draw, align=center, text width=2cm, minimum height=2cm,
  font=\bfseries\scriptsize]
    {\normalsize
     big\\ stuff\\[1ex]
     \normalfont\scriptsize
     Some, small, stuff
     };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Much better. Thanks, also for guessing what I meant and did not write.